# How to turn off SSL validation on an Azure API Management policy?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-service-fabric, azure-api-management, azure-policy

I have APIM setup and i am adding a validate-jwt policy to my apis.  I have my own openid connect server.  however when i add the policy i get an error that it could not connect to my openid-configuration endpoint because it can't validate the certificate.

my identity server is hosted in my service fabric cluster and is in a dev environment so i am using a self-signed certificate.

is there any way to tell APIM to trust the certificate so it can contact my server?

```
<validate-jwt header-name=”Authorization” failed-validation-httpcode=”401″ failed-validation-error-message=”Access token is missing or invalid.”>  
    <openid-config url=”https://myserver/.well-known/openid-configuration” />  
    <required-claims>  
        ...
    </required-claims>  
</validate-jwt>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did u try switch off TLS,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-manage-protocols-ciphers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible at the moment. You could switch to http instead of https in openid-config, if you're comfortable with that.

Comment: Thanks for the response...is there a way to put the information (e.g. signing keys) in the validate-jwt policy itself instead of having it contact the server?

Comment: Yes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT